# Is it possible to obfuscate RTTI data?

Tags: c++, rtti

My project currently is compiled using `-fno-rtti` to prevent `g++` from generating RTTI data in the binary. Now I am at some point where I need RTTI. Is it possible to randomize the RTTI data so the names will not be readable to everyone? Using g++/clang.

Comment: A determined person will be able to reverse-engineer your code even if you haven't any RTTI data in the code. If you need it then just enable it, obfuscation only makes things worse for you and whoever needs to maintain the code after you. As long as you don't have e.g. passwords or similar in class names (or worse, in string literals) then just don't worry about it.

Comment: Also think about this: If you manage to obfuscate the class names in the executable, then you need to use those obfuscated names in your code as well, or add some extra layer of custom RTTI-handling to be able to convert the obfuscated names to the their actual names, and that will leave the names in memory where they can still be read in clear-text, and it will definitely be a lot more work for you and will most likely lead to you reimplementing RTTI with added development and testing time, added complexity and added bugs.

Comment: The funny thing is: I dont directly use `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`. It gets pulled in by `gtkmm`...

Answer (score 1):

No.

If the RTTI data is readable to the computer, then a human can read it.
If not, you can leave it disabled.

Just avoid writing passwords in class names and you should be fine.

Comment: I do not want to remove it completly, just asking if there is a way to randomize the names at compile time or afterwards using a tool.